# Unknown path components - Facebook PHP SDK v4

Tags: php, facebook

I'm just trying to set up the SDK to make a simple call to get details about a page, but I'm getting this error.

Here's the code:

```
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

try {
  $session->validate();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}

$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/v2.3/731857283580130'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

$response = $this->app->json($graphObject);
return $response;
```

The validate() function returns true, so I know that I have the app set up correctly, and if I just visit the url manually then I get the correct results back, so I know it's not a permissions issue:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/731857283580130?access_token=my_id|my_secret
```

But the code gives me this error:

```
Class: Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException
Message: Unknown path components: /731857283580130
Code: 2500
```

What

Comment: Remove the API version. `'/v2.3/731857283580130'` should be just `'/731857283580130'`.